# Connection to SerialPort in C#

Tags: c#, matlab, serial-port

I have been attempting to connect to a serial port using `System.IO.Ports`. I have been having an issue where I do not get a response.

I am attemting to write this:

```
_serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 250, 209, f1, f2, f3, f4, a1, a2, g1, g2, s, 209 }, 0, 0);
var initialResponse = _serialPort.ReadLine();
```

and the response is empty.

Now, what is strange is this works in MatLab

```
s = serial('COM4');
fwrite(s, [250; 209; F1; F2; F3; F4; A1; A2; G1; G2; S; 209], 'uchar');
set(s, 'Timeout', 10);
Response = fread(s, 2)
```

Is there a difference in the byte arrays that could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument in [`Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_Write_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) tells you how many bytes of your array should acutally written. In your case it's 0, meaning the no bytes will be written. Try this:

```
var output = new byte[] { 250, 209, f1, f2, f3, f4, a1, a2, g1, g2, s, 209 };
_serialPort.Write(output , 0, output.Length);
```